# How to select paint for exterior steel door?

Tags: doors, paint

A number of doors will be replaced with flat steel doors:

[image]

The current doors are painted white. The steel door was delivered with a primer coat and is poised for painting.

[image]

When selecting a paint, one would like the finished surface to:

- be durable (think rental property)
- clean easily
- looks presentable if not good

Perhaps there is a better choice of color than white.

That being said: What is the thought process and inputs when selecting a paint for a steel exterior flat door?

Comment: If you are not tied to "must DIY", you may want to check into local options for electrostatic painting. It works best (possibly "only") for metal, but that's what you've got, and it looks great. I had a customer many years ago that got all their file cabinets and other metal office stuff electrostatic painted when they were moving to a new office and the stuff looked fantastic when done.

Comment: Does it need to be white?  White would probably show dirt more and seem to need more cleaning.  For all painting to last, preparation most important, cleaning of surface, using the correct primer and paint.  So you will need exterior primer and paint for metal(steel) surfaces.

Comment: @crip659   I have posted an additional photo to address: "Does it need to be white"?   I do have the final say over as to the color and am open to other  conservative colors.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact   The metal door has a layer of primer.  I wonder if electrostatic is waiting is possible?

Comment: I'm sure it is possible, but don't know how it affects work required and cost

Answer (score 1):

> What is the thought process and inputs when selecting a paint for a steel exterior flat door?

Some door manufacturers will specify a paint to use on their product.

Assuming your door arrived with no such reading material then my thought process would be to select a paint rated for exterior metal like alkyd enamel.

I've always seen it used on stairway rails at my workplace and it's quite durable.

Read the product label to see if you'll have to remove the existing primer.

---

Example:

[image]

Note: I have zero experience with this product nor the results nor am I specifically endorsing this brand.